# nginx not loading all files in subdirectory in laravel project

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-location

I am hosting a laravel project on nginx server on ubuntu 22.02 with subdirectory. home page is loading but its assets like css,js,img files not loading. getting 404 error when i trying to access these files directly. I have created a subdirectory named modernize which contains laravel project.

i tried with the following nginx configuration file

```
`server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name laravel.mainproject.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name laravel.mainproject.com;
  {{root}}

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
  }
  

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }
  
  
   # sub_directory
  location ^~ /modernize {  
      alias /home/mainproject-laravel/htdocs/laravel.mainproject.com/modernize/public;  
      try_files $uri $uri/ @modernize; 
      location ~ \.php$ { 
           fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
           fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        }
     
     
  }  

  location @modernize {
      rewrite /modernize/(.*)$ /modernize/index.php?/$1 last;  
  }
  # end sub_directory
  
  

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}`
```